# Shade alternate plot rows gray

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have created two twin error-bar plots with `ggplot2` and `gridExtra` and I'm now trying to shade the background of every other row on the y-axis in gray.

**Intended output**
[image]

**Data and code**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)

# Reproducible example
dat <- data.frame(dataset=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C"),
                  tis=c("T1", "T1", "T2", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2"),
                  path=c("p1", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p3", "p1" ),
                  NS=c(1.1, 1.2, -0.5, -1.4, -1.6, 0.9, 0.8),
                  min=c(1, 0.4, -0.8, -2, -2, -0.1, 1.5),
                  max=c(2, 2, 0, -1, -0.3, 1.6, 2.1),
                  category=c("c1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c1"))

# Data management
plots_dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(tis) %>%
  group_split() %>% lapply(function(plotDat){

# Plot
ggplot(plots_dat , aes(x=NS, y=path, group=dataset, col=dataset, fill=dataset)) +
      theme_minimal() + 
      geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.7)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1,1), colour="#FA8072", linetype = "longdash") +
      geom_vline(xintercept = c(0), colour="grey", linetype = "solid") +
      geom_errorbarh(height=.3, aes(xmin = min, xmax = max), position = position_dodge(0.7)) + theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
            plot.margin = unit(c(5,5,5,5), "pt"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            text = element_text(size = 14),
            legend.position = "top") + 
      labs(x = "NS", title = plotDat$tis) + 
      xlim(-2.5, 2.5) 
  })

# Join plots
grid.arrange(
    grobs = c(list(
        ggplot(plots_dat[[1]]$data, aes(y = path, x = "")) +
            labs(y = "Path", title = "", x = "") +
            theme_minimal() +
        theme(
            panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
            plot.margin = unit(c(5, 0, 5, 5), "pt"),
            text = element_text(size = 14)
            )
    ), plots_dat),
    nrow = 1,
    widths = c(1.1, rep(1, length(plots_dat)))
)
```

**Current output**
[image]

How can I shade the `p2` row in gray?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply draw the strips before drawing the plots.

First, ensure the plots are transparent:

```r
# Data management
plots_dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(tis) %>%
  group_split() %>% lapply(function(plotDat){
    
    # Plot
    ggplot(plotDat, aes(x=NS, y=path, group=dataset, col=dataset, fill=dataset)) +
      theme_minimal() + 
      geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.7)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1,1), colour="#FA8072", linetype = "longdash") +
      geom_vline(xintercept = c(0), colour="grey", linetype = "solid") +
      geom_errorbarh(height=.3, aes(xmin = min, xmax = max), 
                     position = position_dodge(0.7)) + 
      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
            plot.margin = unit(c(5,5,5,5), "pt"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            text = element_text(size = 14),
            legend.position = "top",
            plot.background = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank()) + 
      labs(x = "NS", title = plotDat$tis) + 
      xlim(-2.5, 2.5) 
  })
```

Next, store the output of `grid.arrange`:

```r
pg <- grid.arrange(
  grobs = c(list(
    ggplot(plots_dat[[1]]$data, aes(y = path, x = "")) +
      labs(y = "Path", title = "", x = "") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(5, 0, 5, 5), "pt"),
        text = element_text(size = 14)
      )
  ), plots_dat),
  nrow = 1,
  widths = c(1.1, rep(1, length(plots_dat)))
)
```

Now draw a gray rectangle on a blank canvas, and draw your result over it:

```r
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(grid::rectGrob(y = 0.48, height = 0.2, 
                               gp = grid::gpar(fill = "gray92", col = NA)))
grid::grid.draw(pg)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Allan, actually it was just a very simple sample to show what I am looking for. In my original data the number of paths on the y-axis will be vary every time I run my code so I need the gray boxes drawn automatically. Is there anyway to make it automatic?

Comment: @Nmgh yes, it's possible, but getting it to work well on a variable number of groups would be complex and would require dozens of lines of code. Unless you are producing an awful lot of these plots, adding gray rectangles to suit is likely to be quicker and easier.